# JavaFX full-screen window: remove popup text

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using

```
window.setFullScreen(true);
```

To make the window full screen.

But ever single time I change scene / pane on the window and make it full screen again it pops us with...

**Press ESC to exit full-screen mode.**

Im guessing this is a built in NetBeans function as it does this on every machine I work on.
Is there any way I can stop this / turn it off or is there another method for full screen that doesn't pop anything annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **"Press ESC to exit full-screen mode ..."** text is coming from the `Stage`, closer from the [`fullScreenExitHintProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#fullScreenExitHintProperty) of the `Stage`.

Parts of the doc (copied from [`getFullScreenExitHint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#getFullScreenExitHint--), emphasis mine):

> Specifies the text to show when a user enters full screen mode,
>   usually used to indicate the way a user should go about exiting out of
>   full screen mode. **A value of null will result in the default
>   per-locale message being displayed. If set to the empty string, then
>   no message will be displayed.**
>
> If an application does not have the proper permissions, this setting
>   will be ignored.

So, if you don't want to see any text, set this property to an empty string:

```
primaryStage.setFullScreenExitHint("");
primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
```

Comment: Thanks man! Now its not really annoying every time I go through my menu system!